# Automatically Apply Coupon on Landing Page - Magento 1.7

Tags: magento

I am using Magento 1.7 and I was wondering if anyone knew how to apply coupons automatically on a landing page. Basically I want the user to come to a specific URL, and when they land on the page I want to apply a %25 discount.

Can anyone point me in the right direction??

Comment: I can't give you a programming answer but this Amasty extension allows you to generate coupons in bulk and apply them via a url parameter.  I've used it and it's very good http://amasty.com/generate-and-import-coupons.html

Comment: I remember reading this a few months back.  I didn't use it but it might help you. - http://www.drewgillson.com/blog/how-to-apply-magento-coupon-codes-automatically/